# How to add a JS Script tag from into React App's ComponentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-optimize

I'm working to use Google Optimize. I need to add this  tag inside my page:

```
<script>(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){s.className+=' '+y;h.start=1*new Date;
h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
(a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
})(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
{'GTM-X':true});</script>
```

to make this work in React, I'm trying the following:

```
import React from 'react';

const MarketingPage = class extends React.Component {
  compomentDidMount = () => {
    (function(a, s, y, n, c, h, i, d, e) {
      s.className+=' '+y;
      h.start=1*new Date;
      h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
      (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
      })(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,
      {'GTM-X':true}
    );
  }
```

React isn't liking this.. I'm getting the following error:

`Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function`

Is it possible to rewrite the code Google Optimize required to be React, linter friendly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's React, but your linter. Just move `(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,{'GTM-X':true})` inside the `()` surrounding the function instead.

Comment: @Tholle would you mind posting the answer? I tried that idea and it didn't seem to make a difference so perhaps I'm misunderstanding. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's React giving your this warning, but your linter.

You could put your function in a variable and invoke it right after instead.

```
const MarketingPage = class extends React.Component {
  compomentDidMount() {
    const analytics = function(a, s, y, n, c, h, i, d, e) {
      s.className+=' '+y;
      h.start=1*new Date;
      h.end=i=function(){s.className=s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?'+y),'')};
      (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;
    };

    analytics(window,document.documentElement,'async-hide','dataLayer',4000,{'GTM-X':true});
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you -- that resolved the last issue now it created a new issue, it's saying `unexpected unnamed function`

Comment: @AnnaSm Alright. I updated the answer. Hopefully that will remove all linter warnings.